# ionic app open from background

Tags: javascript, angularjs, websocket, ionic-framework

I'm using a script that connects through websockets to my ionic app, the problem is that when I'm not active in the app anymore the connections drop and when I open it again it doesn't connect again so I have to fully close it and open it again..

Any suggestions for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code snippet to detect when the app has become active again.  I put this in app.js:

```
    document.addEventListener('resume', function() {
      $rootScope.$broadcast('app:onResume');
    });
```

In some controller file somewhere, set up a listener like

```
$rootScope.$on('app:onResume', function() {
    // code to start the network connection again
})
```